# How to text wrap for placeholder in react formik input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, formik

I have text input field and used FormikTextInput component.
Address field, help text(placeholder) is not wrapping. Can someone help how can we wrap text of placeholder?

The complete content should be wrapped if the resolution is less but not ellipsis.

```
                  <FormikTextInput
                          name="Address"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="124 Example St, Redwood City, CA, 91234"
                        />
```

[image]

Comment: what is the expected behaviour here ? should it be something like `124 Example St, Redwood City, CA .... `

Comment: Outsource the string and use .slice and concatenate it with maybe ...

Comment: @Shyam the complete content should be wrapped if the resolution is less but not this ellipsis

Comment: can someone help me on this?